# Wine can't find gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so

Tags: wine, gnome-keyring

I am trying to start a program using wine on Ubuntu LTS 12.04 64 bit

When I do this, I get the following error message...

> /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux->gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or >directory

When I try to symlink the 64 bit libraries, of course, I get the following...

```
jackie@jackie-Latitude-E6410:~/tmp/AC$ wine TTG.exe
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: 
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
wine: Unhandled page fault on read access to 0x00000000 at address (nil) (thread 0009), 
starting debugger...
err:seh:raise_exception Unhandled exception code c0000005 flags 0 addr 0x7bc47aac
```

Is there a package that installs the 32-bit as well as the 64bit?

UPDATE:

Appears to be a bug in Ubuntu w/ 1.4

https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ppa

I used these steps and my application worked

http://www.noobslab.com/2012/04/install-wine-152-on-ubuntu.html

Not sure exactly why but it appears to ignore the error if you use the 1.5.

Comment: I tried updating Rosetta Stone 4.1.10 to 4.1.15 manually using an update patch, and the I got the same error before and after upgrading wine1.4 to wine1.5. It did not really seem to fix anything. Do I have to completely delete the existing wineprefix and create a new one completely?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This solution works for Ubuntu 12.04 64bit

I originally had this error:

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Then I did a `ln -s` link to the 64-bit lib and got this error:
    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

note: before you start remove the link to the 64bit lib if you created it.

Solution:

Here is how to fix it. Note I am using Crossover 11.3, which uses wine 1.4 so it should also work for wine users.

Further related information to getlibs can be found [here](http://usablesoftware.wordpress.com/2012/05/04/install-lotus-notes-8-5-3-on-ubuntu-12-04-64bit/).

1) Install getlibs:

UODATE 3/2013: Download getlibs from https://github.com/spaetzlecode/getlibs

```
wget https://raw.github.com/spaetzlecode/getlibs/master/getlibs
sudo chown root:root getlibs
sudo chmod +x getlibs
sudo mv -n getlibs /usr/local/bin
```

2) Install the 32bit library:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/getlibs -p gnome-keyring:i386
```

If you got this message error:

```
Failed to download file http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-keyring/gnome-keyring_3.4.1-4ubuntu1~precise1_i386.deb
```

then download the file right here:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3/+files/gnome-keyring_3.4.1-4ubuntu1~precise1_i386.deb
```

and do:

```
/usr/local/bin/getlibs -i "path-of-the-file"/gnome-keyring_3.4.1-4ubuntu1~precise1_i386.deb
```

3) Make the symbolic link:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/ 
sudo ln -s /usr/lib32/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so
```

Now run your Crossover/Wine app and the error is gone.

Comment: For those having error making the symbolic link make a directory named pkcs11 in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu then only you make the symbolic link. I had the same problem before.

Comment: let me suggest to put links in /usr/local/lib/...

Comment: Does this work for you on 12.10? For me it gets rid of the error but my program still does not start up.

Comment: That link for getting getlibs no longer works :( Even the official site of getlibs is down. This is a really bad news, because nothing else seems to fix it. Ubuntu 12.10 x64 did not complain when I softlinked, but it did not fix the problem.

Comment: According to Sidney Sissaoui (shideneyu@gmail.com), getlibs could be found [here](http://developerslog.org/getlibs-all.deb)

Comment: getlibs is unnecessary, you can use apt to download (without installing) debs from repositories in your sources.list: `apt-get download gnome-keyring:i386`. I would provide an answer on how to do fix this using only apt, ar and tar, however I seem to be blocked from answering this question.

Comment: This didn't work in my Ubuntu 13.04. I found [this solution](http://www.techspotde.com/wine-cant-find-gnome-keyring-pkcs11-so/) that did the job.

Comment: If you are on Ubuntu saucy salamander (e.g. [tag:13.10] beta 1) and you get the error message `p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`, then simply do the same commands as above, but also with `p11-kit`: first do `sudo /usr/local/bin/getlibs -p p11-kit:i386` then make the symbolic link: `sudo ln -s /usr/lib32/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so`

Comment: vaab's solution seems so much simpler, and worked for me with 12.04. I suggest trying that first.

Answer (score 47):

The solution to this needn't be any more complex than:

```
sudo apt-get install libp11-kit-gnome-keyring
```

for 64 bit machines. Or

```
sudo apt-get install libp11-kit-gnome-keyring:i386
```

for 32 bit machines.

At least this is the case in 13.04 and I see no reason why that wouldn't hold true in 12.04/12.10.

Comment: I find it odd that the 2 answers above with more votes did not work, did not work in 12.04 through 13.04. But installing the actual package that wine was saying missing as you pointed here worked. Is a shame I had to do the ones mentioned above to then see this answer at the bottom which works.

Comment: that package is not available in Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: apt-get install gnome-keyring worked for me, for 64-bit 12.04

Comment: Installing libp11-kit-gnome-keyring:i386 does not fix the problem in Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: Fixed it for me on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: not found in 12.04

Comment: I'm confused as to why the answer was edited to suggest 64 bit support on 64 bit machines when the issue was clearly 32 bit support on 64 bit machines.

Answer (score 14):

You probably guessed your needed to get the file `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so`. This file is part of an i386 ubuntu package which won't install directly on your amd64 system. But you can get it easily:

```
cd $(mktemp -d)                      ## create and go to a temporary temp dir
apt-get download gnome-keyring:i386  ## download the i386 version of gnome-keyring
ar x gnome-keyring*.deb              ## Uncompress the package
tar xf data.tar.gz
## Finally move the file you need to the desired location:
sudo mv usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/
```

This has happened to me on a `12.10` with `wine-1.5.29`, and i386 `gnome-keyring` version was labeled `3.6.1-0ubuntu1_i386`, and this worked for me.

Please note that if these instruction do not fit for you, maybe should you mention your ubuntu release and `gnome-keyring` version. Thanks !

Comment: the `tar xf data.tar.gz` should be `tar xf data.tar.xz`, at least on my pc... thanks

Comment: actually it didn't work, there is no file named `usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11` in the data folder. Instead there are two directories in `usr/lib`: `usr/lib/gnome-keyring` and `usr/lib/ubiquity`

Comment: @toto_tico: obviously, your ``gnome-keyring`` package is not the same as mine. Could you give more information on your Ubuntu release and ``gnome-keyring`` version ? I added these information to my answer for you to compare.

Comment: Thanks @vaab. I finally found my solution [here](http://www.techspotde.com/wine-cant-find-gnome-keyring-pkcs11-so/). I cannot post the solution because I am new on this community.

Comment: Awesome. Worked with Crunchbang Waldorf

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 14.10 and got the same problem. I tried vaab solution but it did not work for the same reasons as mentionned by toto_tico. Did anybody solve this problem for Ubuntu 14.10 ?

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 14.10 and got the same problem. I tried vaab solution but it failed for the same reasons as mentionned by toto_tico's first message. However the link toto_tico  gave later seems to be irrelevant.  Did anybody solve this problem for Ubuntu 14.10 ?  Note :  are natively installed on my system : libp11-kit-gnome-keyring (ver : 3.10.1-1.ubuntu7), gnome-kyring (ver : 3.10.1-1.ubuntu7), lib-gnome-keyring-common (ver 3.8.0-2).

Answer (score 2):

Another option that worked for me is to simply reinstall libp11-kit0

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libp11-kit0
```

Comment: This had no effect for me on Ubuntu 14.10/

Comment: Why would you downvote an answer for 12.04, with respect to how it works on 14.10...