# p11-kit: Typical problem with Wine

Tags: wine, 13.10

I've installed Wine 1.7 with Winetricks on Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy Salamander. I've tried to launch any .exe files, but still is a problem:

```
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've found a few tips, but anything doesn't work. How can I solve it?

Regards.

Answer (score 21):

I just had the same problem. For me, it was sufficient to install the i386-version of p11-kit using

```
sudo apt-get install p11-kit:i386
```

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit.

Comment: For me this conflicts with 64-bit version :-( (Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit). Apt says: "The following packages will be REMOVED:  gnome-keyring p11-kit python-ubuntu-sso-client ubuntu-sso-client" .

Comment: this seems to be still an issue with Ubuntu 16.04, for me it wanted to remove 
evolution-data-server gnome-keyring p11-kit skypeforlinux

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem and solved it in a very simple way:

All you have to do is to install the `p11-kit-modules:i386` package.
You can do that like this:

```
sudo apt-get install p11-kit-modules:i386
```

And that's it, p11-kit-trust.so is part of this package and will be installed in its correct place.

Hope it helps ;-)

Comment: On a x64 system, this is most likely the most correct answer. Especially if you already have gnome-keyring installed. Thanks!

Comment: this does not try to remove packages on my ubuntu 16.04 x64, so this is the better answer in my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

I just downloaded `p11-kit:i386` with `apt-get download`, extracted the `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so` file (with Archive Manager) and copied it to my `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/` folder.

Hope this helps others to solve the problem without having to install other software.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to follow this other thread and perform [as it mentioned over here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127848/wine-cant-find-gnome-keyring-pkcs11-so)

If you are on Ubuntu saucy salamander (e.g. 13.10 beta 1) and you get the error message

```
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

then simply follow the same commands as in the above link, but also with p11-kit: first do

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/getlibs -p p11-kit:i386
```

then make the symbolic link:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib32/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so
```

Reggie Sep 17 at 17:38

Comment: On a shared WOW64 wine setup this results in wine complaining about the architecture of the shared object.

Comment: On Saucy, I got a conflict when trying to install `p11-kit:i386`, and getlibs was trying to install `ia32libs`, which no longer exists. `sudo aptitude install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0` and then the symbolic link in this answer worked to get rid of the error message in wine.

Comment: I think this worked - I'm at least on to the next bug.  I had to first create some directories I didn't have though.  ie `mkdir /usr/lib32 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11`

Answer (score 1):

A few of the other answers suggest doing this:

```
sudo apt-get install p11-kit:i386
```

This causes conflicts for me, and deinstalls `gnome-keyring`, which is a pretty bad thing. It stops `ssh` from remembering passphrases, and thus you have to keep typing your passphrase in the terminal every single time. And it stops Network-Manager from being able to ask for WiFi passwords.

The one answer that works is

```
sudo apt-get install p11-kit-modules:i386
```

This doesn't have any conflicts.

Manually unzipping packages and installing files is also not a good idea, since you won't automatically get updates, which can lead to security issues.

(Wanted to comment on the correct answer post, but wasn't allowed due to lack of reputation. Figured I'd post to clarify the details for people.)

Comment: -1 for: this question is two years alt, the ubuntu version outdated and the problem, I am sure, is gone for a long time

Comment: Nope. The problem is still around with PlayOnLinux.

Comment: -1 as it copies only other answers.
The problem itself still happens.