# Wine can't load module p11-kit-trust.so

Tags: wine, gnome-keyring

I'm in 13.10 64 bit and I've installed wine from the official repositories. Running wineboot or trying to install any .exe gets me the following message:

```
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: cannot open shared object file:
No such file or directory
```

I've tried the directions from the diferent answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127848/wine-cant-find-gnome-keyring-pkcs11-so/295931) but there is no /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ folder nor a gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so file in the gnome-keyring:i386 package from the official repositories (gnome-keyring_3.8.2-0ubuntu3.1_i386).

Should I be using a different gnome-keyring:i386 package version from the one in the official repositories?

**EDIT**
I solved this by using the suggestion from the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/301356/233390)

Comment: Exactly what package did you install? Did you run `sudo apt-get install wine`? The best way to install wine is by adding it's official repository and installing `wine1.7` from there. The official repositories are very outdated, so you could be experiencing a bug.

Comment: I installed with `sudo apt-get install wine`. I'm gonna go with the wine1.7 version then.

Comment: @Dillmo: Okay, I installed wine1.7 as you suggested and tried again but I get the same message.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this in Mint 16 with Crossover. Possibly related as other solutions (that used to work) no longer do.

Comment: @Cesar, your problem and the one you linked are different. The missing file in the link is `gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so` and yours (and also mine :() is `p11-kit-trust.so`.

Comment: [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/370737/p11-kit-typical-problem-with-wine) worked for me.

Comment: I had the same problem and googled a lot about it and I describe the link I found to solve it here: http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=114671

Comment: I solved this by using the suggestion from this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/301356/233390

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem with Ubuntu 14.4 on an AMD64 box;

Not sure how I ended up in that state, but it was obvious that, inside of firefox, the pipelight/silverlight plugin tried to load two dynamic libraries, and could not find them.

Both were attempted to be loaded as 32bit variant (more specificaly from a directory explicitly designated for 32bit libs.)

The related library files for 64bit architecture where present

```
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I read about some hackish approaches like [ubuntuforums about "p11-kit error Workaround WINE in AMD64 Ubuntu 12.04](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2062150), and tried to install packages with similar names to get the libs.

The tricky part was that the libs are not in the packages where you'd expect them from the packages name, but slightly similary named packages.

So, I found out that these two packages

`p11-kit-modules:i386` and `libp11-kit-gnome-keyring:i386`

need to be installed to fix the two  "couldn't load module" cases.

Note that this did not resolve a third error message line followed direcly to the the lines discussed above:

```
err:secur32:schan_AcquireClientCredentials Could not find matching protocol
```